# Error in compiling: Can't open module file

Tags: fortran

I have this code:

```
        PROGRAM xfit
!   driver for routine fit
    USE nrtype; USE nrutil
    USE nr
    USE ran_state, ONLY : ran_seed
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER(I4B), PARAMETER :: NPT=100
    REAL(SP), PARAMETER :: SPREAD=0.5_sp
    INTEGER(I4B) :: mwt
    REAL(SP) :: a,b,chi2,q,siga,sigb
    REAL(SP), DIMENSION(NPT) :: harvest,sig,x,y
    call ran_seed(sequence=731)
    x(:)=arth(0.1_sp,0.1_sp,NPT)
    call gasdev(harvest)
    y(:)=-2.0_sp*x(:)+1.0_sp+SPREAD*harvest
    sig(:)=SPREAD
    do mwt=0,1
        if (mwt == 0) then
            write(*,'(//1x,a)') 'Ignoring standard deviation'
            call fit(x,y,a,b,siga,sigb,chi2,q)
        else
            write(*,'(//1x,a)') 'Including standard deviation'
            call fit(x,y,a,b,siga,sigb,chi2,q,sig)
        end if
        write(*,'(1x,t5,a,f9.6,t24,a,f9.6)') 'A = ',a,'Uncertainty: ',&
            siga
        write(*,'(1x,t5,a,f9.6,t24,a,f9.6)') 'B = ',b,'Uncertainty: ',&
            sigb
        write(*,'(1x,t5,a,4x,f10.6)') 'Chi-squared: ',chi2
        write(*,'(1x,t5,a,f10.6)') 'Goodness-of-fit: ',q
    end do
    END PROGRAM xfit
```

But when I compile it I get the following error

```
USE ran_state, ONLY : ran_seed
     1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'ran_state.mod' for reading at (1):
              No such file or directory
```

Could you please tell me how I can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather late answer.

1. Get your sub modules and compile:

   `gfortran -c nrtype.f90 nrutil.f90 nr.f90 ran_state.f90`
2. Now link the generated `o` files with your main program: `xfit.f90` and  create the executable, which I've called `main`:

   `gfortran -o main xfit.f90 nrtype.o nrutil.o nr.o ran_state.o`
3. Run the executable:

   `./main`

Answer (score 1):

It is telling you that you need the module ran_state to be built first.  If you compile your module which contains ran_state, then, you will get a .mod file.  If you then build your program, you should no longer get that error.

Comment: Do you get a file called ran_state.mod?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the same error when I built like this:

```
gfortran test.f90 -o test.exe
```

> use modulename
>
> 1
>
> Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'modulename.mod' for reading at
>   (1): No such file or directory

Let's say modulename.mod is in `/usr/local/include` with some dependencies in `/usr/local/lib`.

**You can make the errors go away with the the following:**

```
gfortran test.f90 -o test.exe -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib
```