# `Can't open module file, No such file or directory` when compiling Fortran with an external library

Tags: compilation, fortran

I am currently trying to compile a Fortran 90 code using a module that is supposed to be in a dynamic library libfckit.so. So far my code is:

```
program debug
use fckit_mpi_module
end program debug
```

And for the compilation step I use the following command:

```
mpifc -I/path/to/the/lib debug_fckit.f90 -o debug_fckit.exe
```

I get the following error:

```
use fckit_mpi_module
   1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file ‘fckit_mpi_module.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

I know that this is a common error in Fortran, I searched google but I did not find any satisfying solution for my case.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Your question is not even specific to the old Fortran 90.

Comment: Fortran module information is stored in a `.mod` file. Do you have it? where did you get the library? See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634821/error-in-compiling-cant-open-module-file

Comment: It's not a common error in Fortran.  It is a common error for users who don't know where the module files are located.  Do you have a `fckit_mpi_module` file?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Vladimir and Evets for your comments that helped me to fix the issue. I just added the paths to the directories where the module fckit_mpi_module.mod and the library libfckit.so are. So now my command for compiling the code reads:

```
mpifc -I/path/to/the/directory/where/the/module/fckit_mpi_module.mod/is -l/path/to/the/directory/where/the/library/lifckit.so/is debug.fckit.f90 -o debug_fckit
```

Hope this helps some other noobie like me.